# Windows 7 - XAMPP: vhost keeps redirecting

Tags: apache, windows-7, xampp, virtualhost

**My hosts file. (Win 7 ultimate)**

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       efmm.local
```

**My httpd-vhosts.conf (XAMPP 1.7.3)**

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80

    <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
      DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
      ServerName localhost
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost efmm.local>

        DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\EFMM"
        ServerName efmm.local    
        ErrorLog "logs/efmm.localhost-error.log"
        CustomLog "logs/efmm.localhost-access.log" combined
      <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\EFMM">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
      </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>
```

**Problem**

When I go to `efmm.local` , the browser redirects to `localhost/EFMM`.
I also tried `<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>` instead of `<VirtualHost efmm.local>`, same result.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do it on XP (don't expect it to make any difference in 7)

First, add the virtual host's domain to your HOST (as you did)

I don't put the virtual host webroot under the main htdocs directory. I create a specific webroot next to it, which gives me the following tree:

- C:\XAMPP\htdocs
- C:\XAMPP\htdocs-seconddomain
- C:\XAMPP\htdocs-thirddomain

etc..

So in your case, I would create c:\XAMPP\htdocs-efmm alongside C:\XAMPP\htdocs

Then:

Edit XAMPP's httpd.conf, add and define any Apache options for the new document root, i.e.:

```
<Directory "C:/XAMPP/htdocs-efmm">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All

[any extra apache module instructions you may require]

Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Edit XAMPP's httpd-vhosts.conf, adding the virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName  efmm.local
ServerAlias www.efmm.local
DocumentRoot "C:/XAMPP/htdocs-efmm"
ErrorLog "C:/XAMPP/htdocs-efmm/error.log"
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart XAMPP. You may browse your new virtual host now.